# MySQL InnoDB lock question

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, block

I have a question about MySQL InnoDB. For example: I have the following table created:

```
   mysql>CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SeqNum`
   (
     `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     `seq_num` BIGINT(30) default 0,
      PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

  mysql>INSERT IGNORE INTO `SeqNum` VALUES('current',0);
  Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I have two mysql connections to the same database, I name them as Thread A and B.
In thread A, I have the following SQL statement:

```
    mysql> begin;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select `seq_num` from SeqNum where `id`='current' FOR UPDATE;
       +---------+
       | seq_num |
       +---------+
       |       0 | 
       +---------+
       1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

and then, I just leave the thread A as it is.

In thread B, I would like to do the same query:

```
   mysql> begin;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql>SELECT `current_seq_num` FROM SeqNum WHERE `id` = 'current' FOR UPDATE;
```

thread B will throw an MySQL 1205 Error after the lock waiting time out: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction.

It makes sense, because threadA put a 'X' lock on that row, so that thread B can NOT get the 'X' lock until thread A release the lock.

Now, my question is: from the perspective of thread B, how could I know which thread/connection block my request (to obtain the 'UPDATE' privilege for the table 'SeqNum') when MySQL return Error 1205 to me?
If threadA is doing nothing after it obtains the X lock, and I run 'show processlist' in thread B, all I have are: several threads with 'Sleep' Status (I assume there are more than two threads connected to the datbase), I can NOT identify which thread blocked my request?

Hopefully, I explained the question clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at this stage, the query "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G" could solve my problem.
Here is the info from MySQL manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html#innodb-standard-monitor

run this query in thread B, you will get the thread which blocked your request in "transaction" section

Answer (score 7):

InnoDB plugin will give you a clear picture of the locked and the locking queries.

For instance

```
SELECT r.trx_id waiting_trx_id,  r.trx_mysql_thread_id waiting_thread,
      r.trx_query waiting_query,
      b.trx_id blocking_trx_id, b.trx_mysql_thread_id blocking_thread,
      b.trx_query blocking_query
FROM       information_schema.innodb_lock_waits w
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx b  ON  b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx r  ON  r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id;
```

will give you a locking and blocking transactions. Only you have to have innodb plugin installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can only easily tell if you use a newer (InnoDB Plugin) release.  There are some tables in information_schema which you can query:

- SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;
- SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_locks;

In the innodb_trx table there should be a column called 'trx_mysql_thread_id' (or similar - it is trx_mysql_thread_id in MySQL 5.5).  That is the id in SHOW PROCESSLIST.

(Note that innodb_locks is misnamed.  It will only be populated for lock-waits, not locks).

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a transaction on both sessions, i.e. have you typed

```
START TRANSACTION
```

Normally the behaviour would be as you desire, i.e. a `FOR UPDATE` would just block until the lock were available (due to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` from the first transaction)

Comment: yes, both sessions are in a transaction. I just added the transaction statement in my question. My question is not why the 1st session blocked the 2nd session. But, from 2nd session point of view, how to know which session blocked its request? Of course, I assume there are more than two sessions.

Comment: and I misread your question, I thought you were getting the timeout immediately, I'm sorry!